# Checking dictionary for duplicate values

Tags: python

how can i check if a single dictionary has duplicate values in different keys?  I need to check if duplicates exist and do something if they do, and something else if they don't.

This isn't working for me:

```
In [1428]: mydict
Out[1428]: {'XX': 'foo', 'YY': 'foo'}

In [1430]: for k,v in mydict.items():
      ...:     if v in v:
      ...:         print("we have a match")
      ...:
      ...:
we have a match
we have a match
```

But then testing with a different dict:

```
In [1440]: mydict2 = {"XX":"foo","YY":"bar"}

In [1441]: for k,v in mydict2.items():
      ...:     if v in v:
      ...:         print("match")
      ...:
match
match
```

Not sure why that last one is matching when the values are different.

I need something like

```
for k,v in mydict.items():
   if values match:
       do something
   else:
      do something else
```

thanks

Comment: a string is always in itself. `v in v` is always `True` if `v` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can approach this problem using sets.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
uniqueValueSet = set([])

def has_duplicate_value(dictionary):
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        if v in uniqueValueSet:
            return True
        else:
            uniqueValueSet.add(v)
    return False

mydict = {'XX': 'foo', 'YY': 'xe'}

print("True" if has_duplicate_value(mydict) else "False")
```

Comment: this is great, but i don't quite understand the line `if v in uniqueValueSet:` when that line runs uniqueValueSet is just empty

Comment: This is to check if any value is already present in the set. If it is, then we have encountered a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of a set of previously seen values:

```py
seen = set()
for v in mydict.values():
    if v in seen:
        print("duplicate")
    else:
        print("not duplicate")
    seen.add(v)
```

Comment: This will treat 1st case of duplicate values as not duplicate, which doesn't seem what the OP wants (although not too clear)...

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your use of `if v in v`.  This is equivalent to `if 'foo' in 'foo'`, which will always be true for strings (and would error for values of `1`, `None`, etc.).

One way to look for duplicate values is to invert the dictionary and then check for values with multiple keys, this will give you all collisions (assumes that the values are valid keys [are hashable]):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def invert(items):
   ret = defaultdict(list)
   for k, v in items.items():
       ret[v].append(k)
   return dict(ret)

def duplicates(items):
   return {val: keys for val, keys in invert(items).items() if len(keys) > 1}
```

Then you can find them (and print them how you wish, e.g.):

```
>>> print(duplicates({'XX': 'foo', 'YY': 'foo'}))
{'foo': ['XX', 'YY']}
>>> print(duplicates({'XX': 'foo', 'YY': 'bar'}))
{}
```